# Query date time

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am writing a function to extract date, where my Col1 consists of date and time and my Col2 consists of date only.

`=query({Sheet4!A1:Q},”select Col1, Col2 where Col1 = date ‘”&TEXT(today(),”yyyy-mm-dd”)&”‘ or Col2 = date ‘”&TEXT(today(),”yyyy-mm-dd”)&”‘ “)`

Now, I am facing issue to extract Col1 properly as it misses out some and only extract some of the cells with today’s date.

Answer (score 1):

Change `where Col1 = Date` To `where Col1 contains date`:

`=query({Sheet4!A1:Q},”select Col1, Col2 where Col1 contains date ‘”&TEXT(today(),”yyyy-mm-dd”)&”‘ or Col2 = date ‘”&TEXT(today(),”yyyy-mm-dd”)&”‘ “)`

The equals was trying to look for an exact match from Col1 to the formatted date of today which would never match because of the time stamps.  Anything that was returning with Col1 having todays date was likely because the date of Col1 was the same as Col2.